# Where does the output of a grid volume run in the Saga tool/ Qgis end up?

Tags: qgis, saga, volume

I have tried to do a grid volume run with the Saga grid calculus - grid volume function. After the run the window closes and nothing seems to happen, no message, no new layer or information appear. 
I use a raster .tif as input.

After a run, where does the output normally appear?

Answer (score 1):

This issue was also reported [here](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/8607) a while ago.

The numerical result is printed in the **Log Messages Panel** which you can access by right-clicking the toolbar until you see a list of options and enabling the said panel.

I did a test run and if you scroll down the *Processing* tab, you will see an output that's saved in a Temp folder (although I can't say if it has been modified or if it's the same as the input). But further down you will also see the result which contains the Grid Volume:

[image: Log Messages Panel]

Comment: I managed to find the processing tab.
I guess the base level is set to meters and the volume that comes out as m3? 
I'm quite unhappy with the 0.0xxx results that I got.

Comment: @Lark - Yes, I think you are right in terms of the units. Not sure why you are getting extremely low results though, are you using the latest QGIS and _Processing plugin_ versions?